# Java writing to file - using class

Tags: java

I was reading similar topic to mine at [How to append text to an existing file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java) and have tried solutions there, unfortunately non of them answer my specific case.

I will be creating a lot of changes to a file so I thought that I will create method which will return `PrintWriter` object on which I could do changes by executing `writer.prinln("text");`

```
private static PrintWriter WriteToFile() {

     PrintWriter out = null;
      BufferedWriter bw = null;
      FileWriter fw = null;
      try{
         fw = new FileWriter("smrud.txt", true);
         bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
         out = new PrintWriter(bw);
//           out.println("the text");
         return out;
      }
      catch( IOException e ){
          return null;
      }
      finally{
         try{
            if( out != null ){
               out.close(); // Will close bw and fw too
            }
            else if( bw != null ){
               bw.close(); // Will close fw too
            }
            else if( fw != null ){
               fw.close();
            }
            else{
               // Oh boy did it fail hard! :3
            }
         }
         catch( IOException e ){
            // Closing the file writers failed for some obscure reason
         }
      }
}
```

So in my main method I'm calling this method

```
PrintWriter writer = WriteToFile();
```

Then I'm making changes

```
 writer.println("the text2");
```

and I'm closing writer to save changes to disk:

```
 writer.close();
```

Unfortunately I don't see any changes. When I put changes inside `WriteToFile()` method then I see the changes:

```
private static void WriteToFile() {

     PrintWriter out = null;
      BufferedWriter bw = null;
      FileWriter fw = null;
      try{
         fw = new FileWriter("smrud.txt", true);
         bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
         out = new PrintWriter(bw);
         out.println("the text");
      }
      catch( IOException e ){
         // File writing/opening failed at some stage.
      }
      finally{
         try{
            if( out != null ){
               out.close(); // Will close bw and fw too
            }
            else if( bw != null ){
               bw.close(); // Will close fw too
            }
            else if( fw != null ){
               fw.close();
            }
            else{
               // Oh boy did it fail hard! :3
            }
         }
         catch( IOException e ){
            // Closing the file writers failed for some obscure reason
         }
      }




}
```

But this method open `FileWriter`, `BufferedWriter` and `PrintWriter` every time it will be executed and I wanted to avoid that by returning `PrintWriter` to main method and then executing `writer.println("text");` and after some time close it by `writer.close();` but this don't work.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All the writers are closed in `WriteToFile` so when the `PrintWriter` object is returned it will not write anything.

You will have to increase the scope of the `PrintWriter` and manage it outside the `WriteToFile` method.

Someting like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (PrintWriter printWriter = createWriter()) {
        printWriter.println("Line 1");
        printWriter.println("Line 2");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static PrintWriter createWriter() throws IOException {
    return new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("smrud.txt", true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get your point.

Anyhow, why dont you create your specialized "writer" object? In its constructor you would open {File; Buffered; Print}Writer, then your object will need a `println(String text)` that will forward the string parameter to the appropriate writer. Finelly you'll need a `close()` method that will call close on all your writer objects.

You could also extend this making your object a singleton and synchronizing the print method, allowying your software to print on the same file from different classes.